# Convert keras model architecture to Pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch

I am trying to convert a keras model to pytorch for human activity recognition. The keras model could achieve up to 98% accuracy, while Pytorch model could achieve only ~60% accuracy. I couldn’t figure out the problem, first I was thinking of the padding=‘same’ of keras, but I have already adjusted the padding of pytorch already. Can you check what is wrong?

The keras code is as above

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=[100,12]))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(2))
model.add(layers.LSTM(64))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(13, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

and my pytorch model code is as below

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        seq_len = 100
        # output: [, 32, 100]
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(seq_len, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(32)
        # output: [, 64, 100]
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        # output: [, 64, 50]
        self.mp = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        # output: [, 64]
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(6, 64, 1)
        # output: [, 128]
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 128)
        # output: [, 13]
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 13)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x) 
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.mp(x)
        
        out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        x = out[:, -1, :]
        
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x
```

Comment: What is the input size of your image ?

Comment: The input is a sequence of size [batch_size, 100, 12], where 100 is the sequence length, and 12 is the features. I have found a mistake, the first _Conv_ 's padding = 1, for padding="same". But performance is still bad.

Comment: I have just edited my code.

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer Sorry, didn't notify you in previous comments

Comment: It can also be the way you train the model. For ex, how you adjust your loss etc...

Comment: @IveXu What is the shape in Keras after 1st convolution for this input [batch_size, 100, 12].

Comment: I use CrossEntropyLoss for Pytorch and Adam optimizer with lr=0.001. Just a moment ago, I ran the model for 100 epochs, and the accuracy goes to 92%. I wonder why it takes too many epochs to reach that level of accuracy while keras just need 10 epochs to reach 98%.

Comment: @IveXu If you are exactly converting the keras model you should also use softmax in the end

Comment: I train with Adam optimizer with CrossEntropyLoss
@KnowledgeGainer It is still [batch_size, 100, 32]

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer because Pytorch's CrossEntropyLoss will add Softmax to the predictions, so I have removed the softmax in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was too lengthy to write in the comments,I am writing it in the answer, After testing your PyTorch architecture for shape with random tensor of size which you have mentioned: torch.randn(1, 100, 12)(NCH format).

This is the outcome:

```
input= torch.Size([1, 100, 12])
1st Conv= torch.Size([1, 32, 12])
1st batchNorm= torch.Size([1, 32, 12])
1st relu= torch.Size([1, 32, 12])
2nd Conv= torch.Size([1, 64, 12])
2nd batchnorm= torch.Size([1, 64, 12])
2nd relu= torch.Size([1, 64, 12])
1st maxPool= torch.Size([1, 64, 6])
LSTM= torch.Size([1, 64])
1st FC= torch.Size([1, 128])
3rd relu= torch.Size([1, 128])
2nd FC= torch.Size([1, 13])
```

It is the 100 channels your network is receiving, and as you mentioned in comments after 1st convolution in Keras it's [batch_size, 100, 32]  but in torch it is changing to [batch_size,32,12]

Change to this:

```
def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        in_channels = 12
        # output: [, 32, 100]
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(32)
        # output: [, 64, 100]
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        # output: [, 64, 50]
        self.mp = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        # output: [, 64]
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(50, 64, 1)
        # output: [, 128]
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 128)
        # output: [, 13]
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 13)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax()
```

The output for this will be:

```
input= torch.Size([1, 12, 100])
1st Conv= torch.Size([1, 32, 100])
1st batchNorm= torch.Size([1, 32, 100])
1st relu= torch.Size([1, 32, 100])
2nd Conv= torch.Size([1, 64, 100])
2nd batchnorm= torch.Size([1, 64, 100])
2nd relu= torch.Size([1, 64, 100])
1st maxPool= torch.Size([1, 64, 50])
LSTM= torch.Size([1, 64])
1st FC= torch.Size([1, 128])
3rd relu= torch.Size([1, 128])
2nd FC= torch.Size([1, 13])
```

Comment: 1st Conv will keep the sequence length the same, so the output would be [1, 32, 100], then in maxPool it will pool down to [1, 64, 50].

Comment: @IveXu Yes, but in torch same thing is not happening. The reason is in torchConv1() you are accepting 100 channels instead of 12, that's why in the output 100 channels after conv change to 32 but 12 remains same, because that is the sequence length according to current torch network.

Comment: 100 channels is the sequence length in this case, since kernel_size=3, and padding=1, then the sequence length of 100 will remains, and there are 32 out channels, so it would be [1, 32, 100].

Comment: @IveXu Check the edited answer and it's output, it is working

Comment: @No, I think the in_channels should be 100, which is the sequence length. Just like in Conv2d, the in channels is the image's channels which is 1 for black-white image, and 3 for RGB image. The input size of each channel does not really matter.

Comment: @IveXu Please refer to the output of conv1d here, https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html

It is in the format (N,C,L),
N is a batch size, C denotes a number of channels, L is a length of signal sequence.

Comment: Yeah, so the input would be [N, C, L] = [batch_size, 100, 12], so need to set in_channels=1

Comment: @IveXu No no, See in your Keras network you wrote this line,  model.add(layers.Input(shape=[100,12]))   and also in the comments you mentioned that, 100 is the sequence length and 12 channels(features) right, so in torch in_channels would 12 not 1 because you are passing 12 channels during input.

Therefore input would be- [N,C,L] = [batch_size,12,100]

Comment: Oh I think you are right, in pytorch it would be [batch, in_channels, length], so the features are in_channels, and the length will be the sequence, I 'll try to fix the model.

Comment: @IveXu If you found the answer useful you can accept it and upvote it too. Glad to help you.

Comment: I have fixed the model, now it can achieve 92% accuracy despite need 30 epochs to run. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @IveXu Glad to help you.